# Не получаю ответ от сервера

Tags: c, stm32

Сейчас разрабатываю устройство на STM32 и ENC28J60 по которой надо соединяться к серверу(в качестве сервера ноутбук) по TCP. Контроллер раз в 2 секунды пробует соединиться с ноутбуком. И возникла проблема с подключением по TCP(ноутбук не отвечает на соединение). На ноутбуке стоит обычная программа написанная на Python(код ниже). Пробовал подключаться с разных компов все работает.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()#(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind( ("", 11339))
sock.listen(50)
print("Wait")
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print (conn,addr)
#conn.settimeout(60)
udata = ""
while udata != "end":
        print ("Success...")
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        udata = data.decode("utf-8")
        print("Data from " + addr[0] + ": " + udata)


conn.close()
```

Вот что показывает Wireshark
[image: Пакеты Wireshark]

Вот сама структура пакета
[image: Структура пакета]

Кто знает дайте знать. Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89470/discussion-on-question-by-valik-mahrov-----).